# Userscript to add website screenshot for each google search result?

Tags: firefox-extensions, google-search, search-engines, userscripts

Before the "preview pane" for google web search results came out from their labs, there already were userscripts to have a visual snapshot for each and every website in a web search query result.

Now with the default preview, one needs to hover over the preview button for each site and gets a big (and slower) preview. The older, user-made solutions put the screenshot there for each result element.

How could I achieve to get a screenshot statically for every item in the search result nowadays?